# Why can't Lean4 evaluate my function despite it being defined, Error: compiler IR check failed at '_eval', error: unknown declaration 'g'?

Tags: lean4

My lean4 code:

```
def f (x : Real) : Real := x
#check f
#eval f 3  -- works

noncomputable def g (x : ℝ) : ℝ := 1 / x
#check g
#eval g 3  -- fails
```

but the second fails although it would work for `x=3`. Why and how do I fix this?

error

```
compiler IR check failed at '_eval', error: unknown declaration 'g'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was told

> noncomputable means pretty much exactly “cannot eval/compile”. you can only prove things about them
> 5:10
> so you could prove it equals 1/3 or reduce it or use tactics like normnum but no eval

Answer (score 1):

In Lean, the real numbers are defined as quotients of Cauchy sequences or something like that, so they don't really have a good machine representation to compute with.  In Python, `math.pi` is a floating point number that is approximately equal to $\pi$, but not exactly.  Even `0.1` in Python isn't exactly equal to $1/10$ and that can lead to all sorts of headaches, especially in accounting software.  But in Lean, you need, say, `Real.pi` to be the true number $\pi$, `1/3` to be the true rational $1/3$, and `0.1` to be the true decimal `1/10`, so that means you can't use floating point numbers, or really any finite computable representation of the reals.

Since the definitions for the operations on the reals like division use the axiom of choice, any definition using them can't be compiled to executable code and needs to be marked `noncomputable`.  (Why does real division use the axiom of choice?  You can't programmatically decide if a real number is zero or not from its Cauchy sequence.  It might be zero, or it might be just really close to zero.  So one needs to use the axiom of choice to decide this.)  The short answer is that you shouldn't use `Real` for computation in the compiler or interpreter (`#eval`), nor does `rfl` usually work for reals.  But, many tactics like `norm_num` are really good at "symbolic computation" where they symbolically reduce the Lean expression, so you can prove say `Real.pi / 2 * 2 = Real.pi` with `norm_num`.

---

I'm a bit surprised at the error message you are getting.  The error message in Lean 4.6.0 is a bit better now:

> failed to compile definition, consider marking it as 'noncomputable' because it depends on 'g', and it does not have executable code

It still doesn't say that `#eval` isn't working since your definition is non-computable, but it suggests non-computability is a concern.  What it is sort of saying is that it can't compile the code you are trying to evaluate.

Also, I'm a bit surprised that your `#eval f 3` works.  It gives the same output as `#eval (3 : Real)`, but as you can see the "output" is an infinite Cauchy sequence, so not really something useful for computation.

```
Real.ofCauchy (sorry /- 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ... -/)
```